# How to unlink two objects in the same group?

Tags: 3d-view, groups

[image]

The cube I was messing with somehow "coupled" to the bottle and now i can't select them individually. What happened? Doing Alt+P and Clear Parent doens't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have joined them into one unique object with a <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>J</kbd>, so select it, go in *Edit* mode, select one of the 2 meshes with <kbd>L</kbd> and press <kbd>P</kbd> *(Separate)* > *Selection*